# How to transfer an NFT from a contract address to a wallet address

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, nft, contract-debugging, vyper

In a local test environment, I am able to compile [this](https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/blob/master/examples/tokens/ERC721.vy) implementation of the ERC721 token standard, deploy it, mint an NFT and transfer it (using the `transferFrom` function) to the following deployed vyper contract.

```
def transferFrom(_from: address, _to: address, _tokenId: uint256): nonpayable
    
@external
def transfer_out(_from: address, _to: address, _tokenId: uint256):
    Erc721(_from).transferFrom(_from, _to, _tokenId)
```

**My goal is to transfer the NFT to a wallet from the contract by calling the `transfer_out` function above, but I get the following error when attempting that:**

```
ContractLogicError: execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
```

EDIT:

SOLVED: I was passing the vyper contract's address to `transfer_out` as the `_from` address whereas I should have passed the ERC721 token standard contract's address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not already, you should first [approve](https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/blob/c27f2257cecdc5ba7d89ba7525f580073b84a921/examples/tokens/ERC721.vy#L284) your contract from your EOA to give permission. Then you should be able to transfer the ERC721 token.

And transfer_out function should be:

```
def transfer_out(_from: address, _to: address, _tokenId: uint256):
   Erc721(contract_address).transferFrom(_from, _to, _tokenId)
```

Comment: Thanks (I fixed the function as you recocmmended). I tried both approve and setApprovalForAll on the contract address, and still I get the same error msg when I try `transfer_out`. Is it possible that when a wallet calls `transfer_out` the `msg.sender` is the wallet address and not the contract address? If so I would need to approve the original wallet before transferring it (but that is made impossible by the token standard, i.e. owners can't approve themselves)

Comment: Even though `msg.sender` is the external account, your contract still can't send t he token from your wallet directly without being approved(on the token implementation contract). But if the ERC721 token is already belong to your contract you should be able to send directly. Approval only necessary if a contract is required to send your tokens on your behalf

Comment: yes when I run `transfer_out` the ERC721 token already belongs to the contract. That is why I am so confused about why it doesn't work

Comment: can you also try once with the `safeTransferFrom` instead

Comment: `safeTransferFrom` also does not work

Comment: I think the problem is that after I transfer the token to the contract, the approved address (by calling `getApproved`) for the token is '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', whereas when it is on a regular wallet address the approved address matches the wallet address